# SPARQL search by autoID generated in Protege 5

Tags: sparql, protege

I am a newbie from SPARQL & Prot. I have followed the tutorials in [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9ERlUgvgwM&index=8&list=PLea0WJq13cnAfCC0azrCyquCN_tPelJN1) by Dr Noureddin Sadawi and a bit of the Pizza example tutorial in [Protege Wiki](http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Protege4Pizzas10Minutes). Here it is said that:

"In the Entity URI pane, select **auto ID**. When you create a new class, property or individual P4 will give it a meaningless URI and a readable label. That way if you exchange ontologies, correcting spelling mistakes (by merely changing labels) won’t cause the links between the ontologies to break"

Afterwards, I have created a small ontology for a "user" class with 3 "Data Property": age, email and gender. Then, I created 2 entities in order to make some tests.

In the final stage of my test with Fuseki server as in the Youtube tutorials, but with v2 and I tried to search for one of the users. However, the owl file is generated with the AutoIDs I created the classes and properties, so I don't know how to proceed with **SPARQL**.

For instance, this is one of the entities:

```
<!-- http://localhost/ontologies/2015/user-test#OWLNamedIndividual_84a421a4_9a25_4960_9e94_c8df6e58053c -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&user-test;OWLNamedIndividual_84a421a4_9a25_4960_9e94_c8df6e58053c">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&user-test;OWLClass_a3e98b7d_52be_4a6b_af80_64ea7697332b"/>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="es">user02</rdfs:label>
    <OWLDataProperty_9ade37f6_4e7c_4693_a830_2e0d895b7127 rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">25-34</OWLDataProperty_9ade37f6_4e7c_4693_a830_2e0d895b7127>
    <OWLDataProperty_4492a8ab_183f_4e0d_b456_cbffdaeead79 rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">female</OWLDataProperty_4492a8ab_183f_4e0d_b456_cbffdaeead79>
    <OWLDataProperty_2da03b48_c32a_4c74_91c7_fb552c9c39e5 rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">sus02@hotmail.com</OWLDataProperty_2da03b48_c32a_4c74_91c7_fb552c9c39e5>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

Is this the correct way of proceeding? Which is the best alternative to work with Protege, Jena engine, Fuseki and so on?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you still struggling with this? Or have you found a solution?

Comment: I'm sorry Kunal, I have adopted another solution for the project. Good luck!

Comment: No problem, best of luck to you!